# to move listview data to edit text,

Tags: android

i cant get clearview in this...
i need reuse the listview datas for some purpose, i wish to how to move the listview data to a edittext.. kindly assist with sample code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be having an array which holds the data the list view gets.

You can listen for onItemSelected event on the list, and get the position of the row selected, and then pick up the data at this position in your base array. now put this data into EditText.

This is in the case when you want to put the text into edit text when user clicks a particular row.

Need more help?
revert!